# simple algebraic inequality question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any  $a,b,c$ such that $0 < a < b < c$ ,  prove/disprove:

$\frac{b}{a+b}  + \frac{c}{b+c}  - \frac{c}{a+c} - \frac{1}{2}  > 0$

Comment: I just edited the question to reverse the direction of the inequality. Have not been able to analytically show it. Have run some simulations without any success of finding a counter example either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+b%2F%28a%2Bb%29+%2B+c%2F%28b%2Bc%29+-+c%2F%28a%2Bc%29+-+1%2F2

The denominator is positive, and two of the terms in the numerator are negative, while the remaining term is positive.